# will_paginate NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

Writing sample_app for railstutorial and having next error.

I've added  `<%= will_paginate @microposts %>` to the user profile View and `@microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])` to `UsersController`

```
> NoMethodError (protected method `wp_parse_options' called for #<Class:0x007fde66015a80>):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `show'
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: output on line 17 of `users_controller.rb` is ?

Comment: @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])

Comment: 1. Which action is paginate being used in? 
2. How have you declared the gem for *will_paginate* in the `Gemfile`? 
3. Has the association been set for user `has_many :microposts` and microposts `belongs_to :user`? 4. What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: 1) UserController.show
2) gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre4'
3) yes, everything works without pagination
4) 3.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'` and bundle install again, restart server. Give paginate some extra params just for the hell of it `paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)`

Comment: Please explain clearer that the problem is because he's using a *prerelease* version of a gem, rather than the full version.

Comment: Couldn't have put it better myself

Comment: Thanks, it works. I just copy-pasted this gem versions as newbie)

Comment: Adding extra params "just for the hell of it" was required to fix the same issues for me. Thanks!